# Contar checkboxes marcados dentro de una TableLayout

Tags: android

Tengo una lista de checkboxes y quiero saber cuántos de ellos están marcados antes de continuar con el flujo de la aplicación. Cada uno de los checkbox está en una TableRow dentro de una TableLayout. La lista de checkboxes está escrita de forma manual, no provienen de una Adapter. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener ese conteo sin usar un Adapter? ¿O debo crear mi tabla de forma dinámica?

```
<TableLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/questions_table"
   >
   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:shrinkColumns="0"
       android:stretchColumns="0">
       <TextView
           android:text="Question #1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           />
       <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_01"
           android:checked="true"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           />
   </TableRow>
```

Y así hasta la pregunta 25, con el checkbox cb_25

Comment: Si dices que es manual puedes revisar este enlace http://androidsamplecode.com/en/checkbox

Comment: Debes agregar tu layout, están agrupados? el código?

Comment: Agregué código @Jorgesys

Comment: cual es la vista que contiene los checkbox,  TableRow?

Comment: @Jorgesys Cada uno de los checkbox está en una TableRow, el total de los checkbox está, por lo tanto, dentro de laTableLayout